# SCSS Rails app resources not found when run on command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I would like to run `scss` on the command line in existing Rails apps to generate .css files that I can inspect, etc.

When I run `scss application.scss` in `app/assets/stylesheets` in one app, I get:

```
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
        on line 20 of application.scss
```

Another app:

```
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: resources/*.
       Load path: /Users/me/work/my-app/app/assets/stylesheets/=.
        on line 26 of application.scss
```

I've tried this both in the `app/assets/stylesheets` directory and the project root directory.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm guessing this is due to the [load paths](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import#load-paths) which sprockets sets up for you when compiling sass in the assets pipeline. For what its worth I would just use the `rails assets:precompile` task and save time for something more important.

Comment: Thank you! I am new to Rails and still haven't gotten too far with the JS and CSS stuff. If you would like to put that in the form of an answer I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: You can also just use the web inspector in your browser to view the rendered css files. Its a bit more useful since Rails renders each file seperately in development and you get a source map which helps with for example finding code defined in sass partials.

Comment: That won't help me. I want to refactor some scss code, and need to be able to automate a diff of a large amount of CSS to ensure that I haven't changed anything.